# How to translate "one of the few people" ?

Tags: traduction, expressions

I need to translate the following sentence into french.

> He is one of the few people in the world doing this.

I'm not sure how it goes. My try is "Il est un d'entre une poignée de gens du monde qui font ça."  Please correct me if you feel it strange.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're very close, I'd say:

> C'est l'une des rares personnes au monde à faire ceci.

Comment: "C'est *l'une de quelques personnes* à faire ceci" would work as well, or orner synonyms for "rare".